# Moving files from one folder to an archive folder in same remote directory

Tags: powershell, sftp, putty

I am trying to move remote files from one folder to another but keep getting a failure error.
Code:

```
$command = @("mv /specific/directory/path/source/* /specific/directory/path/destination", "ls //specific/directory/path/source")
$psftpPath = "local/path/to/psftp.exe"
$command |& $psftpPath -pw $password "$User@$Host" -be
```

Error

```
mv /user/specific/directory/path/source/file.extension /user/specific/directory/path/destination/file.extension: failure
```

The ls command does show all the right files in source

Comment: Was it your intention to have 2 / in front of specific for the ls portion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Failure` refers to [status code 4](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes#code_4) with the following common reasons:

> Renaming a file to a name of already existing file.
>
> Creating a directory that already exists.
>
> Moving a remote file to a different filesystem (HDD).
>
> Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).
>
> Exceeding a user disk quota.

I haven't tried your script, but I think that you can can follow the list above as a checklist.

Comment: So since it is for archival purposes, the directory already exists along with files of the same names... so is there a way around that?

Comment: @undetected Sorry, I can't tell now. Check the command-line options of psftp. Perhaps there is one that may help. (I don't have psftp at hands now to test).

Comment: @undetected Just delete the target file before moving the new one in its place.